# custom registration form and captcha validation

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get simple captcha validation at custom registration form?
I have form and line with simple code:

```
<?php 
$factor1 = rand (1,10);
$factor2 = rand(1,10);

$sum = $factor1 + $factor2;

$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance(  );
$wp_session['favcolor'] = $sum;
?>

<div class="bbp-captcha">
    <label for="captcha">Match</label>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $factor1; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $factor2; ?>" disabled />
</div>

<div class="bbp-respond">
    <label for="respond">Result</label>
    <input type="number" name="result" required />
</div>
```

In my functions.php I added:

```
add_filter( 'register_post', 'set_user_register', 10, 3 );
function set_user_register($sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) {

    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance(  ) ;

    if ( $_POST['result'] !== $wp_session['favcolor'] ) {
        $errors->add( 'not_human', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Are you bot?" );
    }
}
```

The only thing I get is `error (not_human)`.

Comment: Are you implementing the captcha with an actual image or...?

Comment: captcha is created with form and stored in $wp_session['favcolor'], then I compare what user data, what you have in functions... No image, just simple match.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How to improve formatting?